# Cloudflare DNS issues

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname

Currently I have linked my website with [cloudflare](/questions/tagged/cloudflare) in order to make us of the [cdn](/questions/tagged/cdn). So what I did was the following:

- Changed nameservers in my hosting to the ones I received from Cloudflare
- Added 2x [cname](/questions/tagged/cname) & [a](/questions/tagged/a) Record to cloudflare

It is for the domainname: autobedrijfvugts.nl

Currently I am receiving a 1016 error which is a Origin DNS error. I checked the website with pingdom and the CNAMES doesn't seem to work.

Could someone help me out with this issue? It's been a day already since the site is offline..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just checked the site and it looks okay to me. I guess the issue is solved?

Comment: Same here, seems to work fine from my station.
What are the cnames?

Comment: I fixed the CNAMES and A Records. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that the CNAME records wasn't correctly set.

It had to be set to the www.